# Problem when training Naive Bayes model in R

Tags: r, r-caret

I am using to Caret package (not had much experience using Caret) to train my data with Naive Bayes as outlined in the R code below. I am having an issue with the inclusion of sentences when executing "nb_model", as it produces a series of error messages, which are:

```
1: predictions failed for Fold1: usekernel= TRUE, fL=0, adjust=1 Error in 
predict.NaiveBayes(modelFit, newdata) : 
Not all variable names used in object found in newdata

2: model fit failed for Fold1: usekernel=FALSE, fL=0, adjust=1 Error in 
NaiveBayes.default(x, y, usekernel = FALSE, fL = param$fL, ...) :
```

Please can you make a suggestion on how to adapt R code below to overcome the issue?

[Dataset used in the R code below](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jcool12/dataset/master/textsentiment.csv?token=AA4LAP5VXI6I7FRKMT6HDPK6U5XBY)

Quick example of what the dataset looks like (10 variables):

```
  Over arrested at in | Negative | Negative | Neutral | Neutral | Neutral | Negative |
  Positive | Neutral | Negative
```

```
library(caret)

# Loading dataset
setwd("directory/path")
TrainSet = read.csv("textsent.csv", header = FALSE)

# Specifying an 80-20 train-test split
# Creating the training and testing sets
train = TrainSet[1:1200, ]
test = TrainSet[1201:1500, ]

# Declaring the trainControl function
train_ctrl = trainControl(
  method  = "cv", #Specifying Cross validation
  number  = 3, # Specifying 3-fold
)

nb_model = train(
  V10 ~., # Specifying the response variable and the feature variables
  method = "nb", # Specifying the model to use
  data = train, 
  trControl = train_ctrl,
)

# Get the predictions of your model in the test set
predictions = predict(nb_model, newdata = test)

# See the confusion matrix of your model in the test set
confusionMatrix(predictions, test$V10)
```

Comment: This looks like an otherwise good question but please remember we don't use personal cloud links on Stack Overflow because they lead to virii and broken links. If the data is available from a package or major website then use that or otherwise please make up pseudo data to use for your example. Having said that, this error - `Not all variable names used in object found in newdata` - means what it says. There's data in your training data that's missing in the new data. I think that often happens if you accidentally include the dependent variable in the training data as a predictor.

Comment: @Hack-R I will ensure I provide pseudo data in the future. I have tried a couple of ways to overcome the issue, but I am finding no way to overcome this issue. Please help with the above R code.

Comment: @Hack-R I have changed the link to GitHub, so it should be easier to import the dataset into R and provided an example above of what the dataset looks like.

Comment: @Hack-R OK, thank you for helping much appreciated.

Comment: @Hack-R OK that's good to know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data set is all character data. Within that data there is a combination of easily encoded words (`V2` - `V10`) and sentences which you could do any amount of feature engineering to and generate any number of features.

To read up on text mining check out the `tm` package, its docs, or blogs like [hack-r.com](http://hack-r.com/n-gram-wordclouds-in-r/) for practical examples. Here's some [Github code](https://github.com/hack-r/LifeVantage) from the linked article.

OK so first I set `stringsAsFactors = F` because of your `V1` having tons of unique sentences

```
TrainSet <- read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jcool12/dataset/master/textsentiment.csv?token=AA4LAP5VXI6I7FRKMT6HDPK6U5XBY"),
                     header = F,
                     stringsAsFactors = F)

library(caret)
```

Then I did feature engineering

```
## Feature Engineering
# V2 - V10
TrainSet[TrainSet=="Negative"] <- 0
TrainSet[TrainSet=="Positive"] <- 1

# V1 - not sure what you wanted to do with this
#     but here's a simple example of what 
#     you could do
TrainSet$V1 <- grepl("london", TrainSet$V1) # tests if london is in the string
```

Then it worked, though you'll want to refine the engineering of `V1` (or drop it) to get better results.

```
# In reality you could probably generate 20+ decent features from this text
#  word count, tons of stuff... see the tm package

# Specifying an 80-20 train-test split
# Creating the training and testing sets
train = TrainSet[1:1200, ]
test = TrainSet[1201:1500, ]

# Declaring the trainControl function
train_ctrl = trainControl(
  method  = "cv", # Specifying Cross validation
  number  = 3,    # Specifying 3-fold
)

nb_model = train(
  V10 ~., # Specifying the response variable and the feature variables
  method = "nb", # Specifying the model to use
  data = train, 
  trControl = train_ctrl,
)

# Resampling: Cross-Validated (3 fold) 
# Summary of sample sizes: 799, 800, 801 
# Resampling results across tuning parameters:
#   
#   usekernel  Accuracy   Kappa    
# FALSE      0.6533444  0.4422346
# TRUE      0.6633569  0.4185751
```

You'll get a few ignorable warnings with this basic example just because so few sentences in `V1` contained the word "london". I would suggest to use that column for things like sentiment analysis, term frequency / inverse document frequency, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, really helpful to understand what I need to do going forward. The sentences in the first column have been identified as either positive, negative or neutral by a series of sentiment lexicons. I am looking to compare the manually classified (V10) with lexicon dictionary results by positive, negative and neutral. I understand that I need to include the sentences when making this comparison. Do you think I am going about this in the right way? Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @jr134 Sure. So, you may want want to remove the original `V1` column entirely then?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I do not need to use the sentences at all and run V2-V10 through? I thought if I do not include the sentences, then this would produce an inaccurate picture, or am I not understanding this correctly?